# drop down like Country / state and City

Tags: jquery

I have chain of drop down like Country / state  and City.
Is there is any way to wait until the drop down population then proceed further?
Some time its works properly. Following are code snipit
Where Country Drop down always populated but State drop populate base on Country Value and City populate base on State value which from Database. Afterwords i need to set State and City option as Selected
In that getOption() populates option base on country state values.

```
success: function(json){                    
                    var obj = JSON.parse(json);                                         

                    $("#country").val(obj[0].BUSINESS_COUNTRY); // Always in populated state
                    $("#state").addOption(getOption("#state",obj[0].BUSINESS_COUNTRY),false);// This populates base on country value using getOption method                                         
                    $("#city").addOption(getOption("#city",obj[0].BUSINESS_STATE),false);   //This populates base on State value



                    setTimeout(function() {                 
                        $("#state").val(obj[0].BUSINESS_STATE);
                        $("#city").val(obj[0].BUSINESS_CITY);
                    },400); 
                }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the selects are chained you'll need to run the ajax on each select's change and then populate the next one in the list. To do that create a generic function that takes the select's type (city, state, or country) and sets the selects below it and bind it to the `change` event.

Something like this:

```
<select id="country"></select>
<select id="state"></select>
<select id="city"></select>

$(document).ready(function() {

    populateLists("country");

    $("#country, #city, #state").change(function() {
        populateLists($(this).attr("id"));
    });

    function populateLists(listType) {

        // do your ajax here (should return an array or string with all corresponding values)

        // on success do this:

        var list;

        if(listType == "country") {
            // populate states
            list; = $("#state");
        } else if(listType == "state") {
            // populate cities
            list; = $("#city");
        }

        for(var i = 0; i < returnedArray.length; ++i) {
         list.append("<option value='" + returnedArray[i] + "'>" + returnedArray[i] + "</option>");
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

this is just a json format.you may refer this json for country,state and city listing.

---

```
$scope.countryList=[
{
    "_id" : "56cbdb338d82d44e4ac2c814",
    "name" : "India"
},
{
    "_id" : "56cc6d8a8d82d44e4ac2c81a",
    "name" : "Pakistan"
}];


$scope.stateList=[
{
    "_id" : "56cc592a8d82d44e4ac2c816",
    "name" : "Maharashtra",
    "country" : {
        "_id" : "56cbdb338d82d44e4ac2c814",
        "name" : "India"
    }
},
{
    "_id" : "56cc594f8d82d44e4ac2c817",
    "name" : "Bihar",
    "country" : {
        "_id" : "56cbdb338d82d44e4ac2c814",
        "name" : "India"
    }
},
{
    "_id" : "56cc59688d82d44e4ac2c818",
    "name" : "Andra-Pradesh",
    "country" : {
        "_id" : "56cbdb338d82d44e4ac2c814",
        "name" : "India"
    }
},
{
    "_id" : "56cc59788d82d44e4ac2c819",
    "name" : "Telangana",
    "country" : {
        "_id" : "56cbdb338d82d44e4ac2c814",
        "name" : "India"
    }
},
{
    "_id" : "56cc6dff8d82d44e4ac2c81b",
    "name" : "Peshavar",
    "country" : {
        "_id" : "56cc6d8a8d82d44e4ac2c81a",
        "name" : "Pakistan"
    }
}];



$scope.cityList=[
{
    "_id" : "56cc7000f9b3225d8885e6c6",
    "name" : "Nanded",
    "state" : {
        "_id" : "56cc592a8d82d44e4ac2c816",
        "name" : "Maharashtra"
    }
},
{
    "_id" : "56cc7000f9b3225d8885e6c7",
    "name" : "Pune",
    "state" : {
        "_id" : "56cc592a8d82d44e4ac2c816",
        "name" : "Maharashtra"
    }
},
{
    "_id" : "56cc7000f9b3225d8885e6c8",
    "name" : "Satara",
    "state" : {
        "_id" : "56cc592a8d82d44e4ac2c816",
        "name" : "Maharashtra"
    }
},
{
    "_id" : "56cc71d3f9b3225d8885e6c9",
    "name" : "Patna",
    "state" : {
        "_id" : "56cc594f8d82d44e4ac2c817",
        "name" : "Bihar"
    }
},
{
    "_id" : "56cc7211f9b3225d8885e6ca",
    "name" : "Adilabad",
    "state" : {
        "_id" : "56cc59788d82d44e4ac2c819",
        "name" : "Telangana"
    }
},
{
    "_id" : "56cc7224f9b3225d8885e6cb",
    "name" : "Tirupati",
    "state" : {
        "_id" : "56cc59688d82d44e4ac2c818",
        "name" : "Andra-Pradesh"
    }
},
{
    "_id" : "56cc7224f9b3225d8885e6cc",
    "name" : "PK-City1",
    "state" : {
        "_id" : "56cc6dff8d82d44e4ac2c81b",
        "name" : "Peshavar"
    }
}];

$scope.tehsilList=[
{
    "_id" : "56d80ce2a5094af2ad65e2ac",
    "name" : "Bhainsa",
    "city" : {
        "_id" : "56cc7211f9b3225d8885e6ca",
        "name" : "Adilabad"
    }
},
{
    "_id" : "56d80d7da5094af2ad65e2ad",
    "name" : "Mudhol",
    "city" : {
        "_id" : "56cc7211f9b3225d8885e6ca",
        "name" : "Adilabad"
    }
},
{
    "_id" : "56d80deaa5094af2ad65e2ae",
    "name" : "Tirupati",
    "city" : {
        "_id" : "56cc7224f9b3225d8885e6cb",
        "name" : "Tirupati"
    }
},
{
    "_id" : "56d80ea4a5094af2ad65e2af",
    "name" : "PK-City1-Tehsil1",
    "city" : {
        "_id" : "56cc7224f9b3225d8885e6cc",
        "name" : "PK-City1"
    }
},
{
    "_id" : "56d80f17a5094af2ad65e2b0",
    "name" : "Dhanapur",
    "city" : {
        "_id" : "56cc71d3f9b3225d8885e6c9",
        "name" : "Patna"
    }
},
{
    "_id" : "56d80fe8a5094af2ad65e2b1",
    "name" : "Satara",
    "city" : {
        "_id" : "56cc7000f9b3225d8885e6c8",
        "name" : "Satara"
    }
},
{
    "_id" : "56d81025a5094af2ad65e2b2",
    "name" : "Pune",
    "city" : {
        "_id" : "56cc7000f9b3225d8885e6c7",
        "name" : "Pune"
    }
},
{
    "_id" : "56d8103ba5094af2ad65e2b3",
    "name" : "Baramati",
    "city" : {
        "_id" : "56cc7000f9b3225d8885e6c7",
        "name" : "Pune"
    }
},
{
    "_id" : "56d81091a5094af2ad65e2b4",
    "name" : "Kinwat",
    "city" : {
        "_id" : "56cc7000f9b3225d8885e6c6",
        "name" : "Nanded"
    }
},
{
    "_id" : "56d8109fa5094af2ad65e2b5",
    "name" : "Loha",
    "city" : {
        "_id" : "56cc7000f9b3225d8885e6c6",
        "name" : "Nanded"
    }
},
{
    "_id" : "56d810c1a5094af2ad65e2b6",
    "name" : "Nanded",
    "city" : {
        "_id" : "56cc7000f9b3225d8885e6c6",
        "name" : "Nanded"
    }
}];
```

---

This is sample application that i have done for cascading and with different form control in angular.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/style/template.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/style/sticky-footer.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/mkcljs.js"></script>
<script src="resources/js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="resources/js/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<script src="resources/js/checklist-model.js"></script>
<title>Sample Form</title>
</head>
<body class="site com_content view-form layout-edit task"
    data-target=".navbar" data-spy="scroll" ng-app="userListA" > 
    <div id="wrap">
        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="navbar-inner">
                <div class="container">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse"
                        data-target=".nav-collapse">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span
                            class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="brand active" href="/"> Sample App </a>
                    <nav class="nav-collapse collapse">
                        <!-- Root menus starts here -->
                        <div id="menu">
                            <ul class="nav">
                                <li><a ui-sref="home">Home Page</a></li> 
                                <li><a ui-sref="masterData">Master Data</a></li> 
                                <li><a ui-sref="addItem">Add Item Data</a></li> 

                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="body">
            <!-- Container started -->
            <div class="container">
                <div class="header">
                    <div class="header-inner" > <ui-view>

                        <br> <br>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row-fluid">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="push"></div>
    </div>
<!--<div id="dob_datepic" class="date">
<input placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" readonly="readonly">
<span class="add-on" id="icon"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></span>


</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("#dob_datepic").datepicker({
        format:"dd/mm/yyyy",
        autoclose:true,
    });
});


</script>-->
<script type="text/javascript">
var parentModule=angular.module("userListA",["ui.router","checklist-model"]);

parentModule.config(function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider){
    //$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/addItem");
    $stateProvider

    .state('addItem',{
        url:'/addItem',
        templateUrl:'htmlviews/validations.html',
        controller:'validationCtr'
    }).state('masterData',{
        url:'masterData',
        templateUrl:'htmlviews/masterData.html',
        controller:'masterDataCtr'
    }).state('viewData',{
        url:'/viewItemData',
        templateUrl:'htmlviews/ViewData.html',
        controller:'viewDataCtr'
    }).state('masterData.addstate',{
        url:'/addstate',
        templateUrl:'htmlviews/addState.html',
        controller:'addStateCtr'
    });
});
parentModule.controller("validationCtr",function($scope,$http,$window){

    $scope.getDatafromDB=function(){
        $http({
            url:"demouser/getAllDatafromDB",
            method: "GET",          
        }).success(function(data,status){

            $scope.itemLocalList=data;
            $scope.isUpdate=true;
            $scope.isDelete=true;

        }).error(function(data,status){

        });
    };

    $scope.clearLocalStorage=function(){
        $window.localStorage.removeItem("itemList");
        $scope.itemLocalList={};
    };

    if($window.localStorage.getItem('itemList')!=null)
    {
        console.log("in local list");
        $scope.itemLocalList=JSON.parse($window.localStorage.getItem("itemList"));
        $scope.isUpdate=false;
        $scope.isDelete=false;
        console.log($scope.itemLocalList);
    }
    else 
        {
        $scope.getDatafromDB();
        }


    $http({
        url:"demouser/getHobbies",
        method: "GET",

    }).success(function(data,status){
        $scope.hobbies=data;
        console.log($scope.hobbies);
    }).error(function(data,status){
        alert("error");
    });

    $http({
        url:"demouser/getCountries",
        method: "GET",

    }).success(function(data,status){
        $scope.conutries=data;
        console.log($scope.conutries);
    }).error(function(data,status){
        alert("error");
    });
    //$scope.item=JSON.parse($window.localStorage.getItem("item"));
    $http({
        url:"demouser/getCountrywiseState",
        method: "GET",

    }).success(function(data,status){
        $scope.states=data;
        console.log($scope.states);
    }).error(function(data,status){
        alert("error");
    });

    $scope.savetolocal=function(){
        var items=[];
        if($window.localStorage.getItem("itemList")!=null)
            {
            items.push.apply(items,JSON.parse($window.localStorage.getItem("itemList")));
            }
        items.push($scope.item);
        $window.localStorage.setItem("itemList",JSON.stringify(items));
        $scope.item={};
        //$scope.itemLocalList=JSON.parse($window.localStorage.getItem('itemList'));
        //console.log("itemLocalList"+ $scope.itemLocalList);
    };
    $scope.savetoDB=function()
    {
        $http({

            url: "demouser/saveBulkData",
            method: "POST",
            data: JSON.parse($window.localStorage.getItem("itemList"))

        }).success(function(data,status){
            console.log("Data synced to database sucessfully");
            $scope.getDatafromDB();
            $scope.clearLocalStorage();
        }).error(function(data,status){
            console.log("failure");
        })
    };

    $scope.updateRecordinDB=function(item){
        $http({
            url: "demouser/updateRecord",
            method: "POST",
            data: item

        }).success(function(data,status){
            console.log("Data upadted to database sucessfully");
            $scope.item={};
        }).error(function(data,status){
            console.log("failure"); 
        })
    }
    $scope.deleteItem=function(item){
        $http({
            url: "demouser/deleteRecord",
            method: "POST",
            data: item

        }).success(function(data,status){
            console.log("Data deleted to database sucessfully");
            $scope.item={};
        }).error(function(data,status){
            console.log("failure"); 
        })
    }
    $scope.getItem=function(itm){

        $scope.item=itm;
    }

});

parentModule.controller("masterDataCtr",function($scope,$http,$window){

});

parentModule.controller("addStateCtr",function($scope,$http,$window){

    $http({
        url:"demouser/getCountries",
        method: "GET",

    }).success(function(data,status){
        $scope.conutries=data;
        console.log($scope.conutries);
    }).error(function(data,status){
        alert("error");
    });
});


</script>
    <!-- Footer -->
    <div class="footer">
        <div class="container">
            <hr />
            <p class="pull-right">
                <a href="#" id="back-top">Back To Top</a>
            </p>
            <p>&copy;Copyright 2014-15 Maharashtra Knowledge Corporation Ltd.
                All Rights Reserved.</p>
        </div>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

---

```
<form class="form-horizontal" name="frm">

                    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label required">Item Name</label>
    <div class="controls">
    <input type="text" ng-model="item.itemName" name="itemName" ng-minlength="3" ng-maxlength="25" required/>
    <span ng-show="(frm.itemName.$error.required || frm.itemName.$error.minlength || frm.itemName.$error.maxlength) && frm.itemName.$dirty">Please fill the item name.</span>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label required">Item Code</label>
    <div class="controls">  
    <input type="number" ng-model="item.itemCode" name="itemCode" ng-min="18" ng-max="100" required/>
    <span ng-show="(frm.itemCode.$error.required || frm.itemCode.$error.min || frm.itemCode.$error.max) && frm.itemCode.$dirty ">Please fill the item code with valid number.</span>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label required">Email</label>
    <div class="controls">  
    <input type="email" ng-model="item.email" name="email" ng-pattern="/^[_a-z0-9]+(\.[_a-z0-9]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$/" required/>
    <span ng-show="(frm.email.$error.required || frm.email.$error.pattern) && frm.email.$dirty ">Please enter valid email address.</span>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label required">Gender</label>
    <div class="controls">  
    <input type="radio" ng-model="item.gender" name="gender" value="M" required>Male</input>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="item.gender" name="gender" value="F" required>Female</input>

    <span ng-show="frm.gender.$error.required && frm.gender.$dirty ">Please enter valid email address.</span>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label required">Gender</label>
    <div class="controls">  
    <label ng-repeat="hobby in hobbies">
    <input type="checkbox" checklist-model="item.hobbies" checklist-value="hobby" name="hobby" >{{hobby.name}}</input>  
    </label>

    <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label required">Country</label>
    <div class="controls">  
    <select ng-options="country as country.name for country in conutries track by country.name" ng-model="item.conutries" >
    <option value="">Select Country</option>
    </select>   
    </div>  
    </div>

    <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label required">State</label>
    <div class="controls">  
    <select ng-disabled="!item.conutries" ng-options="state as state.name for state in states | filter:{$:item.conutries.name} track by state.name" ng-model="item.states" >
    <option value="">Select State</option>
    </select>   
    </div>  
    </div>

    <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label required">DOB</label>
    <div class="controls">  
    <div class="date" id="datepicker_dateOfBirth">
    <input ng-model="item.dob" name="dob" placeholder="DD/MM/YY" readonly="true" required>
    <span class="add-on" id="icon"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></span></div>
    </div>  
    </div>

    <br/>
    <div class="controls">
    <button  type="submit" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="savetolocal()">Save to Local</div>
    <button ng-show="isUpdate" type="submit" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="updateRecordinDB(item)">Update</div>
    </form>

    <div ng-if="itemLocalList.length>0">
    Search:<input type="text" ng-model="searchText"/> 
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" >
    <thead> 
    <tr>    
    <td>Item Name</td>
    <td>Code</td>
    <td>Cust Email</td>
    <td>Gender </td>
    <td>dob </td>
    <td>Hobbies</td>
    <td>Country</td>
    <td>State</td>
    <td>Update</td>
    <td>Delete</td>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody> 

    <tr ng-repeat="itm in itemLocalList | orderBy: ['itemName','itemCode'] | filter :{itemName: searchText}" >
    <td>{{itm.itemName}}{{itm._id}} </td>
    <td>{{itm.itemCode}} </td>
    <td>{{itm.email}} </td>
    <td>{{itm.gender}} </td>
    <td>{{itm.dob}} </td>
    <td><label ng-repeat="hby in itm.hobbies">{{hby.name}} </label> </td>
    <td>{{itm.conutries.name}} </td>
    <td>{{itm.states.name}} </td>   
    <td><button ng-show="isUpdate" ng-click="getItem(itm)">Update</button></td>
    <td><button ng-show="isDelete" ng-click="deleteItem(itm)">Delete</button></td>
    </tr> 
    </tbody>
    </table>

<div class="control-group">
<div class="controls">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="savetoDB()">Sync Data to DB</div>
</div>
    </div>              

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="push"></div>
    </div>
<!--<div id="dob_datepic" class="date">
<input placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" readonly="readonly">
<span class="add-on" id="icon"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></span>


</div>-->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("#datepicker_dateOfBirth").datepicker({
        format:"dd/mm/yyyy",
        autoclose:true,
    });
});


</script>
```

---

```
package mkcl.os.apps.controllers;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import mkcl.os.apps.services.NoSQLCrudService;

import org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CustomDateEditor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.WebDataBinder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.InitBinder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
@Controller
@RequestMapping("demouser")
public class UserController {

    @InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        dateFormat.setLenient(false);
        binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(dateFormat, true));
    }



    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "saveUserAJAX", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void saveCandidate(@RequestBody String user) {
        NoSQLCrudService modelLessCrudService=new NoSQLCrudService();
        modelLessCrudService.saveCollection("user", user);
    }


    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "getUserAJAX", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getUserAJAX(@RequestParam String id) {
        NoSQLCrudService modelLessCrudService=new NoSQLCrudService();
        String user=modelLessCrudService.findOne("user", id);
        return user;
    }

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "getHobbies", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getHobbies() {
        NoSQLCrudService modelLessCrudService=new NoSQLCrudService();
        String hobbs=modelLessCrudService.getAllRecords("hobbies");
        return hobbs;
    }

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "getCountries", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getCountries() {
        NoSQLCrudService modelLessCrudService=new NoSQLCrudService();
        String cntryList=modelLessCrudService.getAllRecords("country");
        return cntryList;
    }

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "getCountrywiseState", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getCountrywiseState() {
        NoSQLCrudService modelLessCrudService=new NoSQLCrudService();
        String stateList=modelLessCrudService.getAllRecords("state");
        return stateList;
    }

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "saveBulkData", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void saveBulkData(@RequestBody String itemList) {
        NoSQLCrudService modelLessCrudService=new NoSQLCrudService();
        modelLessCrudService.saveCollection("itemList", itemList);      
    }

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "updateRecord", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void updateRecord(@RequestBody String item) {
        NoSQLCrudService modelLessCrudService=new NoSQLCrudService();
        modelLessCrudService.save("itemList", item);        
    }
    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "deleteRecord", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void deleteRecord(@RequestBody String item) {
        NoSQLCrudService modelLessCrudService=new NoSQLCrudService();
        modelLessCrudService.delete("itemList", item);      
    }

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "getAllDatafromDB", method = RequestMethod.GET,produces="application/json;charset=utf-8;")
    public String getAllDatafromDB() {
        NoSQLCrudService modelLessCrudService=new NoSQLCrudService();
        String itemList=modelLessCrudService.getAllRecords("itemList"); 
        return itemList;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="employee.aspx.cs" Inherits="ClassTest.employee" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function Savedata() {
            Country_Get();
           
        });
        function Savedata()
        {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'employee.aspx/insert',
                type:'post',
                contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
                datatype: 'Json',
                data: "{A:'" + $("#textname").val() + "',B:'" + $("#textage").val() + "',C:'" + $("#ddlcountry").val() + "',D:'" + $("#ddldept").val() + "'}",
                success: function(){
                alert('insert success !!')
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert('data error !!')
                },

            });
        }

        function Country_Get() {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'employee.aspx/Country_Get',
                type: 'post',
                contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
                datatype: 'Json',
                data: "{}",
                success: function (_dt) {
                    _dt = JSON.parse(_dt.d);
                    for (var i = 0; i < _dt.length; i++) {
                        $("#ddlcountry").append($('<option/>').attr("value", _dt[i].Cid).text(_dt[i].Cname));
                    }
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert('data error !!')
                },

            });
        }

    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Name:</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="Textname" /></td>
        </tr>

         <tr>
            <td>Age:</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="Textage" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Country:</td>
            <td><select id="ddlcountry">
                <option value="0">-----select-----</option>
                </select></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="button" id="btnsave" value="Save" onclick="Savedata()" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```